# Create an images slideshow (JPG) with the image duration based on EXIF date delta

Tags: image, slideshow, exif

I want to create photo slideshows where the display duration of each photo is somehow based on the EXIF date difference between it and its successor. 
The photos are (irregularly taken) images of one specific scene (say a building being built) and I want to create some kind of chronologically linearized slide show. I took more photos when more visible stuff happened and less when nothing really happened and I want to compensate for this in the slideshow.

I don't really care whether the result is a GIF animation, movie file or bash script that remote controls an image viewer. If an application is required it can be commercial (but should be affordable) - though I would of course prefer OSS based solutions. Only the end result must be portable (Linux, OS X, Windows) and based on open data formats.

I could of course write a script that takes the smallest time delta of all photos and duplicates other photos where necessary and creates a slideshow with fixed time intervals out of the resulting list, but I wonder if there are solutions requiring less amount of work.

Bonus points are awarded for

- configurable stretch factor (seconds per day etc)
- logarithmic time scaling (so pics taken in very short intervals don't just stay visible for 1/100s)
- an iPhoto / Apple Photos export plugin that does this. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started, as I was feeling bored this afternoon. Basically, it whizzes through all JPG photos in the current directory and extracts the time at which each was taken. The time is then converted to epoch seconds and the names of all the photos are output with their associated times and sorted into order:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Accept JPG and/or jpg as file extension
shopt -s nocaseglob

# Go through all photos
for f in *.jpg; do

   # Use jhead to get date and convert that to epoch seconds for easy sorting
   epoch=$(jhead "$f" | awk '/^Date/{s=$3 " " $4;gsub(/:/," ",s);print mktime(s)}')

   # Output result
   echo $epoch:$f
done | sort -n
```

**Output**

```
1395388852:P3210013.JPG
1395388894:P3210014.JPG
1395388908:P3210015.JPG
1395388917:P3210016.JPG
1395388941:P3210017.JPG
1395499771:P3220018.JPG
```

If you then want to make an animated GIF, you can use ImageMagick (which I woud install on OSX using `homebrew`) like this:

```
convert -delay 400 P5280158.JPG -delay 200 P5280159.JPG -loop 0 anim.gif
```

which will make an animated GIF holding the first photo for 4 seconds and the second one for 2 seconds in an infinite loop (`-loop 0`) like this:

[image]

Comment: Still thinking about a solution. But yours is a good start. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm writing a Ruby script based on your solution. I'll post it on Github when it is finished. But of course it needs to deserve to be called at least v0.1 before that .. :)